# Dynamic Range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

I am having hard times figuring out how to pass a dynamic range into the formula.

Usually I will have a scenario where I know in what column my range is going to be (example below), where LR is number of rows in my range.

```
Range("A1:A" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = ....some formula here
```

Problem begins when I have to create a range dynamically using (in my case) column header name. I can find the column by Header Name, get column number, convert it into letter, but any of the solutions I've tried didn't work.

This is what I use to get column number:

```
Function getColumn(searchText As String, wsname As String) As Integer
    Set aCell = Sheets(wsname).Rows(1).Find(what:=searchText, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If aCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("Column was not found. Check spelling")
            Exit Function
        Else
            getColumn = aCell.Column
        End If
End Function
```

This code I use to convert it into the letter:

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Now, to populate the formula in the range I tried something like that, but unfortunately no luck:

```
colLetter = Col_Letter(manuallyAdjustedNumber)
Range(colLetter & "2:" & colLetter & LR).FormulaR1C1 = "=EXACT([RC-1],[" & harnessDrawingNumber & " - " & manuallyAdjustedNumber & "])"
```

I will apreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: can you confirm you are getting the correct Letter Value from your Col_Letter() function?

Comment: `Debug.Print` that formula and try using it in the worksheet. It's not what you think it is. Your brackets are off.

Answer (score 4):

Forget changing to a letter and just use `Cells`

```
 With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(2,manuallyAdjustedNumber),.Cells(LR,manuallyAdjustedNumber)).FormulaR1C1 = ...
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You are making this ***way*** too complicated.  Why you are using R1C1 notation and at the same time converting everything back and forth from column letters to column numbers is completely beyond me.

You have 2 problems:

- You are always working with the ActiveWorkbook (the example below makes that explicit).
- You need to makes sure that the *Worksheet* is found.

It should look something more like this:

```
Public Function GetColumn(searchText As String, wsname As String) As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If LCase$(.Name) = LCase$(wsname) Then
                Dim header As Range
                Set header = .Rows(1).Find(searchText, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlNext, False)
                If Not header Is Nothing Then
                    GetColumn = header.Column
                    Exit Function
                End If
                MsgBox ("Column was not found. Check spelling")
                Exit Function
            End If
        End With
    Next
    MsgBox "Worksheet '" & wsname & "' not found."
End Function
```

Comment: @BigBen You're right, I didn't notice that. Not enough information in the question to determine what it should be though.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I am identifying worksheets earlier in the code, I just wanted to be more specific and not post 900 lines of code here ;-) My main problem was identifying the correct range based on header.